# Unable to ssh vm machine(VM Player) from local machine

Tags: ssh, apache-http-server

I am trying `apache-drill`with Sandbox by MapR following [documentation](http://drill.apache.org/docs/installing-the-apache-drill-sandbox/).
I installed virtual machine from VMPlayer and opened a vm `MapR-Sandbox-For-Apache-Drill-1.0.0-4.1.0-vmware.ova.`

After login, it got started successfully. Then I tried to ssh this vm from my local machine following [tutorial](http://drill.apache.org/docs/getting-to-know-the-drill-sandbox/) using command:

`ssh mapr@localhost -p 2222`

But I got the error

> ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you double-check the VM settings to ensure that NAT port forwarding is enabled?  Can you SSH into localhost inside the VM itself?

Comment: @dev : Check whether SSH is installed or not?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath ssh is installed,

Answer (score -1):

As I am trying to ssh from my local machine to VM, so instead of `ssh mapr@localhost -p 2222` command would br `ssh mapr@<IP of VM> -p 2222`